# No route matches for destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The destroy action is working for me in one part of my app, but I can't get it to work in a different view that is using a separate controller.

I am getting the error: `No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"letsgo"}`

View:

```
<% for letsgo in @letsgos %>
<li>
<b>Let's Go...<span class="content"><%= letsgo.content %></span></b> 
<%= link_to 'Delete', { :controller => 'letsgo', :action => 'destroy'}, 
                      { :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :remote => true} %>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
  resources :letsgos, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

LetsGos controller:

```
  def destroy
    @letsgo.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

This code works if I am under the `letsgos` view: `<%= link_to "delete", letsgo, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }%>`

Destroy action works if I am working under the `letsgos` view, but I am working under a different folder it no longer works. What I am doing is listing all the `content` from the `letsgos` table, and providing a destroy action for each content.

Routes:

```
                letsgos_eatdrink GET      /letsgos/eatdrink(.:format)                   letsgos#eatdrink
             letsgos_listenwatch GET      /letsgos/listenwatch(.:format)                letsgos#listenwatch
                    letsgos_play GET      /letsgos/play(.:format)                       letsgos#play
                   letsgos_other GET      /letsgos/other(.:format)                      letsgos#other
                 letsgos_explore GET      /letsgos/explore(.:format)                    letsgos#explore
                   repost_letsgo POST     /letsgos/:id/repost(.:format)                 letsgos#repost
               interested_letsgo POST     /letsgos/:id/interested(.:format)             letsgos#interested
                                 GET      /letsgos(.:format)                            letsgos#index
                                 POST     /letsgos(.:format)                            letsgos#create
                      new_letsgo GET      /letsgos/new(.:format)                        letsgos#new
                     edit_letsgo GET      /letsgos/:id/edit(.:format)                   letsgos#edit
                                 GET      /letsgos/:id(.:format)                        letsgos#show
                                 PATCH    /letsgos/:id(.:format)                        letsgos#update
                                 PUT      /letsgos/:id(.:format)                        letsgos#update
                                 DELETE   /letsgos/:id(.:format)                        letsgos#destroy
```

Comment: what is the result of command: ```rake routes``` ?

Comment: @TomHert routes added

Comment: Don't you need to pass in the `:id` of the `@letsgo` object you want to delete in your `link_to` delete line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the ID of the `letsgo` to the route:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', { :controller => 'letsgos', :action => 'destroy', :id => letsgo.id }, 
                      { :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :remote => true} %>
```

As written in your paths:

```
letsgo DELETE   /letsgos/:id(.:format)                        letsgos#destroy
```

*It's not tested, but should be like this*

Comment: I implemented the `letsgo.id` before posting here and it was giving me a routes error so I removed it. To give the exact error with it added, `No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"letsgo", :id=>9}`.

Comment: So there is mistake also in the ```:controller => 'letsgos'```, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#static-segments

Answer (score 0):

THIS WORKS FOR me too! Just add `DATA:` before `{ :confirm..... }`  ...and the Confirm Delete Dialog works.

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', { :controller => 'letsgos', :action => 'destroy', :id => letsgo.id },
               data:  { :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :remote => true} %>
```